# Expansive mapping has convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $z\in X$, and $T:X\to X$ such that $d(x,y)\leq d(T(x),T(y))$ for any $x,y\in X$. Define $x_1=T(z)$ and $x_{n+1}=T(x_n)$ for $n\geq 1$. Show that $(x_n)_n$ has a subsequence that converges to $z$.

My attempt: Fix $\epsilon>0$. Since $X$ is compact, $(x_n)_n$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ that converges to some point $x\in X$. So there is an $N$ such that $k\geq N\implies d(T(x_{n_k-1}),x)=d(x_{n_k},x)<\epsilon$.

Now I want to show that $d(x,z)<\epsilon$, and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it will follow that $x=z$. $d(x,z)\leq d(T(x),T(z))\leq d(T(x),x_1)\leq d(T^2(x),T(x_1))=d(T^2(x),x_2)\leq...\leq d(T^n(x),x_n)$.

Since $n_k\geq n$ by definition of a subsequence, $d(T^n(x),x_n)=d(T^n(x),T^n(z))\leq d(T^{n_k}(x),T^{n_k}(z))=d(T^{n_k}(x),x_{n_k})$, so if we can show this is less than $\epsilon$ we are done. At this point I'm trying to figure out how to use the first bound $d(x_{n_k},x)<\epsilon$.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed or if this is even the right idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:I note the $n$-th composite of $T$ by $T^{[n]}$. With your notations, by applying $T^{[n_k]}$ you have for $p\geq 1$
$$d(T^{[n_{k+p}-n_k]}(z),z)\leq d(T^{[n_{k+p}]}(z),T^{[n_k]}(z))=d(x_{n_{k+p}},x_{n_k})$$

so for $\varepsilon>0$ and $k,p$ large you have $d(x_m, z)<\varepsilon$ with $m=n_{k+p}-n_k$.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!

Comment: @user124910 You are welcome